# How do I generate (train, test) folds where each test fold contains features generated by the corresponding train fold?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For example, consider the iris dataset and suppose my goal is to predict sepal length.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
train = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
train['Species'] = iris.target
train

     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  Species
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2        0
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2        0
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...      ...
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3        2
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8        2
```

I'd like to split the data into 5 folds (train1, test1), (train2, test2), ... Now consider the fold (train1, test1).  Using train1, I want to measure the average sepal width, petal length, and petal width per Species, and then map those averages to test1 (based on Species).  And then I want to do this for the remaining folds.

Ultimately I'd like to do this in a way that allows me to use `GridSearchCV` to train a `RandomForestRegressor` using those same folds. Is there a convenient method of doing this with scikit-learn?

I realize this seems silly for this example but I think it makes sense for my real dataset.

Comment: `I want to measure the average sepal width, petal length, and petal width per Species, and then map those averages to test1` - It's hard to understand why this would make sense. Can you give a toy example for which you can explain the rationale behind that?

Comment: @cel I'm guessing your inclination would be to one-hot-encode the species values?  Well, suppose there were 50 different species instead of 3.  And suppose your data had 10 more categorical features, also with high cardinality.  If you one-hot-encoded everything, you'd end up with a huge sparse matrix of many underlying features.  This poses a number of issues (both in terms of computation costs and model degradation).